# no matching function error in the case of relation between base class and extend class

Tags: c++, matching, base-class

I got two classes: TJob and Reload_Job. Reload_Job extends from TJob:

```
class reload_job: public TJob
```

I got a function:

```
void run_all_threads(std::vector<TJob*> &jobs){...}
```

and a call:

```
std::vector<reload_job*> jobs;
thread_pool->run_all_threads(jobs); //error: No matching function
```

A got an error at that call. However, if i changed the function's form into:

```
void run_all_threads(TJob* job)
```

and the call:

```
reload_job* job;
thread_pool->run_all_threads(job); it work
```

Could you guys help me explain that why I got an compling error in the case of vector of Tjob pointer. Thanks so much!

Comment: A vector of cats is not a vector of animals, if you want to think of it that way.

Comment: Does the compiler understand that a vector of cat is a vector of animal. So, how can I pass a array of cat into a function, which only receive a array of animals?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue stems from the fact that vector< reload_job* > is not a sub-type of vector< TJob* >, even though reload_job is a sub-type of TJob.

In your first example, the compiler searches for a function with the signature `run_all_threads(vector < reload_job* >)`. There is no function with that signature.

```
void run_all_threads(std::vector<TJob*> &jobs){...}
std::vector<reload_job*> jobs;
thread_pool->run_all_threads(jobs); //error: No function matches run_all_threads(vector <reload_job*>)
```

However, in your second case, reload_job is a TJob, so the compiler matches the functions.

```
void run_all_threads(TJob* job)
reload_job* job;
thread_pool->run_all_threads(job); The compiler matches the function
```

To solve your issue, change the parameter to the function to be a `vector< TJob* >`. You can store the reload_jobs in a `vector < TJob* >`, since reload_job is a TJob.

```
void run_all_threads(std::vector<TJob*> &jobs){...} // function signature doesn't change
std::vector<TJob*> jobs; // this vector can store TJob and/or reload_job
thread_pool->run_all_threads(jobs); // now the types match
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written similar kind of class skeleton where i didn't see any problem.
Will you give more details about your class implementation.

class TJob
{
public:
    TJob()
    {
    }

};

class reload_job: public TJob

{

public:
   reload_job()
   {

}

void run_all_threads(std::vector &jobs)
 {

}
};

int main(){

```
std::vector<TJob*>vec;
vec.push_back(new reload_job());

reload_job rj;
rj.run_all_threads(vec);
```

return 0;

}

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful examination. I copy your code and compile again, and then receive the same error:"no matching function for call to ‘reload_job::run_all_threads(std::vector<TJob*, std::allocator<TJob*> >&)’"

Comment: besides, your method: "run_all_threads(std::vector &jobs)" should be: "run_all_threads(std::vector<reload_job&> jobs)"

Answer (score 0):

The function takes a `std::vector<TJob*>` and you try to pass it a `std::vector<reload_job*>`. It really is that simple. These are different vectors, even though their contents are convertible.